# Cloud Foundry yaml parse error

Tags: yaml, cloud-foundry

I'm getting an error on cf push when I try to push a yaml file for a memcached service broker:

```
#cf push
FAILED
Error reading manifest file:
yaml: [] mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2, column 7
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:95 (0x2c0d87)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 (0x16276)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:144 (0x2c1609)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:161 (0x2c17e5)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:471 (0x2c3cd4)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:196 (0x2c1c6e)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:394 (0x2c336d)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:193 (0x2c1d38)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:171 (0x2c199e)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/candiedyaml/decode.go:137 (0x2c146d)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/manifest/manifest_disk_repository.go:82 (0xb13ef)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/manifest/manifest_disk_repository.go:50 (0xb0f72)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/manifest/manifest_disk_repository.go:33 (0xb0e13)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/manifest/manifest.go:1 (0xb300e)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application/push.go:377 (0x23e2c3)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application/push.go:356 (0x23e062)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application/push.go:120 (0x23ada2)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/command_runner/runner.go:50 (0xa70a9)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/command_runner/runner.go:1 (0xa73d4)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/app/app.go:76 (0x8ecce)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli/command.go:101 (0xcb140)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli/app.go:125 (0xc9654)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/main/main.go:154 (0x3729)
/Users/pivotal/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Testing/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/main/main.go:91 (0x2eb9)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:220 (0x1804f)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1394 (0x1a580)
```

So obviously someethign is wrong with my yaml file. But I don't know what. Here's what I have:

```
domain: cloudeast.mycompany.com
  nats:  secret
    machines:
      - 10.10.100.10
    password: secret
    port: 4222
    user: nats

  networks:
    apps: default
    management: default

  memcache_broker:
    broker_password: secret
    memcache:
      vip: 10.100.100.100:11211
      servers:
      - 10.100.100.101:11211
      - 10.100.100.102:11211
    plans:
      small:
        name: small
        description: A small cache with no redundency
        free: true

  memcache_hazelcast:
    heap_size: 512M
    host:
      src_api: https://memcache-hazelcast.cf-deployment.com
      password: secret
    memcache:
      secret_key: secret
    hazelcast:
      max_cache_size: 268435456
      machines:
        zone1:
        - 10.100.100.101
        zone2:
        - 10.100.100.102
    plans:
      small:
        backup: 0
        async_backup: 1
        eviction_policy: LRU
        max_idle_seconds: 86400
        max_size_used_heap: 100
      medium:
        backup: 0
        async_backup: 1
        eviction_policy: LRU
        max_idle_seconds: 86400
        max_size_used_heap: 200
```

Could I get some help with why this yaml file isn't parsing correctly?

Comment: @Anthon has explained why your YAML is invalid.  But after correcting it this will not be a valid cf manifest.  Are you intending to run the broker as an app running on CF itself, or running on its own somehow (e.g. BOSH-deployed), because some of the data you have in your file looks like what would go into a BOSH manifest for deploying CF itself, rather than an app running on CF.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta thanks for expanding on that. I'm not familiar with cloudfoundry, I  looked at their documentation page and could find anything related to config file format and gave up after searching for it for 10 minutes.

Comment: An application running on CF can be configured using command line flags, or via a config file that is called a "manifest" file.  It looks like you made that file intentionally, here's more details about manifest files: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html.  It's not clear what larger problem you're trying to solve though.  Since you're not that familiar with cloud foundry, are you sure you need to be deploying a service broker from memcached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first line you have a scalar (`domain`) followed by a colon (`:`) followed by a scalar (`cloudeast.mycompany.com`), this means at the top, non indented, level you start a mapping and `domain` is a key scalar and `cloudeast.mycompany.com` a value scalar.

On the next line you should, once more, have a key scalar and it has to be indented at the same level as the previous line (or you finish the top-level mapping with an end of stream (`...`) or start a new document (`---`). You start an indented value that is a mapping and the parser doesn't know what you want to do with that.

One can only try and guess what you try to do. If `cloudeast.mycompany.com` is the name of the domain, you should make that a new indented scalar value (with key `name`), then the same indentation error occurs for the key `machines`. and following 3 keys, after that the file is OK:

```
domain: 
  name: cloudeast.mycompany.com   # scalar key "name" added
  nats:  secret
  machines:                       # this scalar key and next 3  dedented
  - 10.10.100.10
  password: secret
  port: 4222
  user: nats

  # from here everything as it was
  networks:
    apps: default
    management: default

  memcache_broker:
    broker_password: secret
    memcache:
      vip: 10.100.100.100:11211
      servers:
      - 10.100.100.101:11211
      - 10.100.100.102:11211
    plans:
      small:
        name: small
        description: A small cache with no redundency
        free: true

  memcache_hazelcast:
    heap_size: 512M
    host:
      src_api: https://memcache-hazelcast.cf-deployment.com
      password: secret
    memcache:
      secret_key: secret
    hazelcast:
      max_cache_size: 268435456
      machines:
        zone1:
        - 10.100.100.101
        zone2:
        - 10.100.100.102
    plans:
      small:
        backup: 0
        async_backup: 1
        eviction_policy: LRU
        max_idle_seconds: 86400
        max_size_used_heap: 100
      medium:
        backup: 0
        async_backup: 1
        eviction_policy: LRU
        max_idle_seconds: 86400
        max_size_used_heap: 200
```

Of course you also leave out the cloudeaset.mycompany.com value. In both the cases the top level of the YAML file will be a mapping with a single key scalar: `domain`. The value for that key is again a mapping with keys like `nats`, `networks`, `memcache_broker`