# Syntax error in processing yaml

Tags: yaml

I have the following yml:

```
  mongo:
    version: 2.6.9
    repo: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/RPMS/
    maxconns: 40
      standalonedb_host: myhost0001.ab-xy.aws.com
      standalonedb_port: 8399
      standalonedb: "{{standalonedb_host}}:{{standalonedb_port}}"
```

I get a syntax error though, on the `standalonedb_host` line. What am I doing wrong?

*edit:* Oddly enough, if I de-indent the `standalonedb` vars, the errors go away. If I add spaces again, the error returns.

Comment: Did you use tab for your indentions? YAML does not like the tab character.

Comment: newp, it's all white space

Comment: Well...that was the extent of my YAML knowledge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Foundry yaml parse error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903081/cloud-foundry-yaml-parse-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a key/value pair nested under a key/value pair ie `standalonedb_host: myhost0001.ab-xy.aws.com` (and the rest of the `standalonedb_*` config) is nested under `maxconns: 40`.

Depending on your configuration, either of the following should fix the issue:

- Remove the nesting:

  ```
  mongo:
    version: 2.6.9
    repo: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/RPMS/
    maxconns: 40
    standalonedb_host: myhost0001.ab-xy.aws.com
    standalonedb_port: 8399
    standalonedb: "{{standalonedb_host}}:{{standalonedb_port}}"
  ```
- Remove the value in `maxconns` so the `standalonedb_*`-related hash becomes the value of the `maxconns` key:

  ```
  mongo:
    version: 2.6.9
    repo: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/RPMS/
    maxconns:
      standalonedb_host: myhost0001.ab-xy.aws.com
      standalonedb_port: 8399
      standalonedb: "{{standalonedb_host}}:{{standalonedb_port}}"
  ```